# Copy text from scanned pdf

Tags: adobe-acrobat, ocr

I have some scanned documents, which I want to copy the text from.

Adobe Acrobat Pro recognizes the text, however it is placed in a bunch of bounding boxes, making it impossible (?) to just mark all the text and copy it elsewhere.

[image]

Is there any way to get all the text from the document without clicking through each of the boxes, either by making AAP ignore the boxes, or scripting it or something?

Is there some other software more suited to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Scanner, you can use the option "Scan as editable text".  My HP Printer Scanner offers this option.

Or try Optical Character Recognition software

Try Abbyy Fine Reader    https://www.abbyy.com/en-ca/finereader/